# How to remember page in table when navigating back

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table in page A, and can by clicking on entries in the table jump on a new page B for detailed editing.

Right now, when I navigate back to the table on page A, the table reloads on page 1. This can be painful when editing a number of entries in the middle of a large table.

I would like the UI to remember which page I was on. Is there a painless way of doing it ?

**Update**: I get the reload when navigate back through the browser back button OR the window.history.back() method.

Yes, I probably reload the datasource. For a reason, since I have some selectors on page A that fiddle with query filters), but I'll see if I can avoid the reload. I don't really know how to do it without remembering my previous state.

Comment: How are you navigating back to page A? I have a similar type of set up to edit records from a table I go to a 'Detail' page, then I have a button on the Detail page that simply navigates back to the table page. In your setup it sounds like you are reloading the datasource for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out that I really don't need to reload the data source at attach. I just need to do it as I change the queryfilters in page A. Then however I also need to remember to change pageIndex back to 1, because somehow THAT is remembered.

Thanks for the help!